# calculate line number in another branch

Tags: git, branch, git-diff

After a bit of research I still don’t know if this is possible through just native git commands, but I am trying to find a way to compute the line number of a certain line on my current branch in another branch (if it exists), through code. The best idea I have is to run `git diff` on the branches and doing manual searching, which seems inefficient and prone to errors. Does anyone have a better ideas on how this can be done? Thank you for your time and help.

Say for example I had a branch `y`, and has a file `F` with line number `126`. That same line on branch `x` is line `90`. How do I find out that the line is on line `90` through code / git commands?

Cheers

Comment: Did you mean something like `git grep -n ... $BRANCH -- $FILE`?

Comment: @0andriy no, I don't want to use `grep` because that's hard to account for duplicates of code etc. Say for example I had a branch `y`, and has a file `F` with line number `126`. That same line on branch `x` is line `90`. How do I find out that the line is on line `90` through code / git commands?

Answer (score 0):

Git automates the backtracking part with `git log -L`, say you want to track line 6 back through time in file1.c `git log -L 6,6:file1.c` and it'll show you.

But I think nobody's taught it to do that in reverse, to trace evolution *forward*.  To use the existing machinery you'd have to make a history-reverser and run down the cousin-branch evolution on that. It wouldn't be *that* hard, and a structure-only nonce commit is only like a hundred bytes... sure, why not. This passes a smoketest on a middling-sized history,

*edit: fixed a bonehead mistake, original post somehow had the version _before_ I got it working*

```
branch2=your/other/branch
base=`git merge-base @ $branch2`
declare -A mymap
while read original children; do
    newparents=""
    for child in $children; do newparents+=" -p ${mymap[$child]}"; done
    mymap[$original]=`git commit-tree $newparents -m $original $original:`
    [[ $original = $base ]] && break;
done <<EOD    
    $(git rev-list --ancestry-path --children $base^! $branch2)
EOD
```

Then plug in the start and end line numbers you tracked your current tip back to into

```
git log -L $start,$end:file1.c ${mymap[$base]}
```